# Referring to 'i'th element of list in R

Tags: r

I've got a problem in R.
I have loaded files from folder (as filelist) using this method:

```
ff <- list.files(path=" ", full.names=TRUE)
myfilelist <- lapply(ff, read.table)
names(myfilelist) <- list.files(path=" ", full.names=FALSE)
```

In myfilelist I have dataframe name as: A1.txt, A2.txt, A3.txt.. etc

Now I would like to use the 'i'th element of list to change my data, for example
with each data frame delete rows the sum of which = 0.

I tried:

```
A1 <- A1[which(rowSums(A1) > 0),]
```

and it works. 
How can I do it for all `A[i]` at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
lapply(myfilelist, function(x) {
                       x <- x[which(rowSums(x) > 0),]
                       return(x)
                   })
```

Comment: The anonymous function needs a return value: `sapply(myfilelist, function(x) {x[rowSums(x) > 0,]})`

Comment: @Roland Thanks a bunch for pointing this out.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Why using `sapply`? It may change the structure of `myfilelist`. `lapply` should be used instead.